# Selenium 2.0b3 and IE9/Firefox 4

Tags: testing, selenium

I nabbed Selenium 2.0b3 after seeing the announcement that it now works with Firefox 4 and IE9.

Unfortunately, I experience the same issues prior to 2.0b3 - I can't find elements in IE.

The exact same tests work just fine in IE8, Firefox 3 and any version of Chrome.

I thought these new browsers were now supported?

Comment: Not sure if this is a question. The browsers are supported and I use them already. If you have a bug can you raise it at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your OS is windows 7 or vista, you need run your selenium server as administrator.

Comment: This is the answer. :(  I took all the steps I saw on the site (set target sites as trusted, etc) but didn't think to elevate it.