# Selenium-dot-net-2.0rc3 with Firefox 5 - How do I run selenium server as admin?

Tags: selenium

I just downloaded Selenium-dot-net-2.0rc3 and ran my tests on Firefox5. Firefox browser window opens up and goes to directed url but eventually it fails with error -OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:

I read similar question on stackoverflow - titled " [Selenium 2.0b3 and IE9/Firefox 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502032/selenium-2-0b3-and-ie9-firefox-4) " and the solution to this was to run selenium server as administrator.

I am guessing that this might be what I need as I am running tests on Windows 7.

Can anyone tell me how do I run selenium server as administrator?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the command prompt as adminstrator.

Do `Start`, search for `command prompt` and then right-click and click `run as administrator`